# Сравнение элементов двух массивов String через Stream

Tags: массивы, строки, java-stream

Есть два массива `String[] arr1` и `String[] arr2`, нужно собрать новый массив `String[]` или `ArrayList`.
Как цикл в примере реализовать с помощью stream?

```
for(String a1 : arr1) {
   for(String a2 : arr2) {
     if(a1.equals(a2))
        list.add(a2);
   }
}
```

я пробовал что-то вроде этого, но что-то некак

```
String[] arr3 = (String[]) Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(arr1.length).map(i -> (arr1[i].equals(arr2[i]))).toArray();
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Склеить или сравнить?

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос уточнениями - кнопка "править"

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов что не понятно в моем вопросе?

Comment: Теперь после комментариев к вопросу и его правок он стал понятен.

Answer (score 2):

Все элементы первого, встречающиеся во втором:

```
Arrays.stream(a1).filter(s1 -> Arrays.stream(a2).anyMatch(s2 -> s1.equals(s2))).toArray(String[]::new)
```

Comment: На выходе должен получиться массив String[] arr3

Comment: @FatCat Необходимо передать генератор String[]::new в метод toArray. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!